# Close date and Status in SFDC

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

If I had a list of 200 opportunity IDs, is there a way to pull their close date and status? I know I could build a report and filter by ID, but would that filter accept that number of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. A **report** can have 2 filters (excluding the built-in filters like Date or "my/my team's/ all records").

But what you can do is take the ids and make 1 long list of them, separated by commas. The field for value you filter by can be 1333 characters long so with commas it's 1333/(18+1) = 70 Ids.

You can build a report with filters `1 OR 2 OR 3` and `OpportunityId = list_1_70, OpportunityId = list_71_140, OpportunityId = list_141_200`

With **SOQL** query (you could execute it in developer console or data loader?) it could of course be `SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN ('006...', '006...', '006...')`

SOQL can be 100K long. 200 * (18 chars + 2 apostrophes + comma) = 4200, should be well under the limit.